# How to get dashed lists in french and bullet lists in english with babel in the same document?

Tags: lists, itemize, babel, babel-french

In a bilingual document, using `babel`, I want to have a dashed list when the main language is French, and a bullet list when the selected language is English.

Here is a MWE showing that switching to English does not typeset `itemize` lists as expected.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[main=french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
Cette partie du texte est composée en français avec :
\begin{itemize}
\item une liste ;
\item \enquote{à puces}.
\end{itemize}

\selectlanguage{english}
This part is in english with:
\begin{itemize}
\item a \enquote{bullet};
\item list.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The layout doesn't differ only in the labels, french also changes the spacing. So you should at first consider carefully, what exactly you want to restore at language changes.

Comment: I want to illustrate typographical differences between languages, and how to manage them with LaTeX. It seems the two can't be done at the same time in a simple way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding

```
\frenchsetup{GlobalLayoutFrench=false}
```

in the preamble?

See all options available in the English documentation `frenchb.pdf` or in the French one `frenchb-doc.pdf`.

Both are part of the latest version of babel-french package on CTAN. You can also get them from http://daniel.flipo.free.fr/babel-french

Comment: @JouleV: I have added links in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This works as expected. Documentation says setting `GlobalLayoutFrench` to `true` changes lists and first paragraphs, but not the footnotes (command `\StandardFootnotes` can be used instead), when switching language. Are there other implications?

Comment: No, the documentation is correct: only footnotes' layout will not be affected. If you want to show both layouts (standard and French) in the same document for footnotes, you'll have to set flag `\FBFrenchFootnotesfalse` locally to display a standard footnote (French being the main language).